# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression; don't understand why

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by

Getting the error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression. I'm not sure why this is happening. Everything seems correct. Am I missing something blatantly obvious here?

```
SELECT  to_number(CALOT_AWD_YR),
    CALOT_TPC,         
    ATCAT_ALLOT_NBR,
    ATCAT_TCAT,
    SUM(CALOT_AMT_FUNDED),
    ATCAT_C_OR_D_IND

FROM MYSCHEMA.STG_TED_CLNT_ALLOT_TAB, 
 MYSCHEMA.STG_TED_ALLOT_TCAT
WHERE  CALOT_TPC       =   ATCAT_TPC
 AND  CALOT_AWD_YR    =   ATCAT_AWD_YR
 AND  CALOT_ALLOT_NBR =   ATCAT_ALLOT_NBR
 AND  CALOT_TPC       in ( 'DL' , 'PL' , 'TH' )
GROUP BY CALOT_AWD_YR,
     CALOT_TPC,
     ATCAT_ALLOT_NBR,
     ATCAT_TCAT  

ORDER BY CALOT_AWD_YR,
     CALOT_TPC,
     ATCAT_ALLOT_NBR,
     ATCAT_TCAT;
```

Comment: your query is missing `ATCAT_C_OR_D_IND` in the `group by`

Answer (score 3):

You need to group by ATCAT_C_OR_D_IND as well

Answer (score 2):

The column `ATCAT_C_OR_D_IND` in your `select` list isn't in the `group by` clause. You either need to remove it from the `select` list, apply some aggregate function to it, or add it to the `group by` clause in order to make your query legal.